# Self-closing template elements stopping rendering in Lift

Tags: xml, scala, templates, lift

I'm using `bind()` to replace XML elements in my template with String values, like so:

```
bind("foo", nodes, "bar" -> "My Content")
```

When I use a self-closing element in my template, like so:

```
What I want to see is <foo:bar />, and everything after it.
```

I'll *occasionally* get this:

```
What I want to see is My Content
```

and *not* this:

```
What I want to see is My Content, and everything after it.
```

But when I change the template to use a non-self-closing empty element:

```
What I want to see is <foo:bar></foo:bar, and everything after it.
```

I'll *always* get the fully rendered content.

I haven't yet been able to figure out what triggers the erroneous behaviour for self-closing tags.

Is this merely a Lift bug, or is there some reason for this to occur?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is with the HTML parser that Lift uses. For most tags, it doesn't recognize the self close and will assume that the content after it is content within the tag (hence it gets stripped). The same problem will exist if you attempt to use `<div />` or similar tags in combination with CSS selectors. I'm not sure it is a bug per se, as that [seems to be the expected behavior in HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3558119/are-self-closing-tags-valid-in-html5) (at least according to the accepted answer's last bullet point).

Comment: That makes sense if Lift was using the strict non-XML HTML5 parsing rules. But when they mark it up with their own namespaced elements, they've already crossed the border into XHTML... and so should support self-closing tags. Sigh.

Comment: Yeah, I do agree that can be a problem. I think that is partially why the trend has been moving away from 'lift' prefixed tags and bindings and towards using CSS selectors bound to `class` and `data-lift` attributes on existing tags. It keeps the markup as valid HTML and can make tracking down errors a little easy with a validation tool.

Comment: Which is a fine way to go... except if you don't already have an HTML tag to piggyback on. :-\ Thanks though!